# Not able to update ui view in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using trying to update a show/hide a div using `ng-if` where the value of ng-if updated from controller.Also I am using  `Controller as` syntax instead of $scope

HTML file

```
<div layout="row" ng-controller="TabColController as tc">
    <div ng-if="tc.hasErrors">
            Currently this part of the site is not working
        </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
var tableColumns={
    tableColumns:function(tabColFactory){
        this.hasErrors = false;
        this.getTiersData=function(param){
            let params = {
                url:'tierData'
            };
            tabColFactory.getTiers(params).then(function(resp){
                this.hasErrors = true;
            //consoling this here is showing value of hasError as true, but div is not yet shown in UI
                console.log(this); 
              this.filterTierOneData(resp);
            }.bind(this),function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this);

         this.filterTierOneData=function(resp){ }.bind(this);
        return this.getTiersData();
    }
};
export default tableColumns;
```

Comment: I'm guessing `this` is not what you think it is, try logging it